# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, hybrid-mobile-app, android-sdk-tools

I want to create an Android Native library which can connect any native Android application to React Native code.

Instead of using Node modules locally, I have published react dependency on Maven and downloading dependencies from there. But once after project is build it is unable to run the application.

Error log:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libjscexecutor.so caused by: dlopen failed: library "libjsc.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~14knnd-kjEhJL_02K42nIw==/com.awesomeproject-x7RG89XX5hc_Coi7jXdZ4g==/lib/x86_64/libjscexecutor.so in namespace classloader-namespace result: 0
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:918)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl(SoLoader.java:740)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:654)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:634)
    at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:582)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you find any solution?